# Why is the second title "Chemicals" stuck on the right in this unordered list format?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 unordered lists where I am floating 50% to the left and 50% to the right.  I like how "Materials" is positioned and I want "Chemicals" to position to the left (like "Materials") but I'm not sure what else to try.

I have tried floating "Chemicals" paragraph to the left and setting a text-align to the left.

```html
<div class="labskillsbox">
  <!--Lab Skills - Janky Code.. -->
  <p><strong><em>Materials</em></strong></p>

  <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
      <li>MeasureNet station and a pH meter</li>
      <li>Drop counter</li>
      <li>Two 50-mL burets</li>
      <li>Buret brush</li>
      <li>BBs container</li>
      <li>Stopwatch</li>
      <li>250-mL beaker</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
      <li>150-mL beakers</li>
      <li>Stir bar</li>
      <li>Ruler</li>
      <li>25-mL graduated cylinder</li>
      <li>Plastic funnel</li>
      <li>Buret clamp</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    <p><strong><em>Chemicals</em></strong></p>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
      <li>Vegetable oil</li>
      <li>Walnut oil</li>
      <li>Extra virgin olive oil</li>
      <li>Light olive oil</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
      <li>Mobil motor oil</li>
      <li>Quaker State motor oil</li>
      <li>0.025 M sodium hydroxide (NaOH)</li>
      <li>Ethanol</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

I expect "Chemicals" to position similarly to "Materials" (to the left).

Comment: ***Here is an image of the output:*** https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D_klybIW4AAsJN5.jpg:large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is float problem, use clear property when you use float

```
style="clear: both;"
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Testing</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 </head>

 <body>
 <div class="labskillsbox">      <!--Lab Skills - Janky Code.. -->
      <p><strong><em>Materials</em></strong></p>

      <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <ul>
          <li>MeasureNet station and a pH meter</li>
          <li>Drop counter</li>
          <li>Two 50-mL burets</li>
          <li>Buret brush</li>
          <li>BBs container</li>
          <li>Stopwatch</li>
          <li>250-mL beaker</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
        <ul>
          <li>150-mL beakers</li>
          <li>Stir bar</li>
          <li>Ruler</li>
          <li>25-mL graduated cylinder</li>
          <li>Plastic funnel</li>
          <li>Buret clamp</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;">
  <p><strong><em>Chemicals</em></strong></p>
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
      <li>Vegetable oil</li>
      <li>Walnut oil</li>
      <li>Extra virgin olive oil</li>
      <li>Light olive oil</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
      <li>Mobil motor oil</li>
      <li>Quaker State motor oil</li>
      <li>0.025 M sodium hydroxide (NaOH)</li>
      <li>Ethanol</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this answer is correct, please do give it an upvote as well as mark it correct by clicking on the tick. It will help others identify the correct answer in future.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your "Chemicals" paragraph is still floated to the right is because the left halve of the ul element above it is larger than the one on the right. This means that the Chemicals element is directly below the one on the left, and it can't float into the area of the right half.

A quick fix is to wrap both halves of the ul in a div and give it a height like so:

```
<div style="height: 200px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
      <ul>
        <li>MeasureNet station and a pH meter</li>
        <li>Drop counter</li>
        <li>Two 50-mL burets</li>
        <li>Buret brush</li>
        <li>BBs container</li>
        <li>Stopwatch</li>
        <li>250-mL beaker</li>
      </ul>
   </div>

    <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
      <ul>
        <li>150-mL beakers</li>
        <li>Stir bar</li>
        <li>Ruler</li>
        <li>25-mL graduated cylinder</li>
        <li>Plastic funnel</li>
        <li>Buret clamp</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="labskillsbox">
  <!--Lab Skills - Janky Code.. -->
  <p><strong><em>Materials</em></strong></p>
  <div style="height: 200px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
      <ul>
        <li>MeasureNet station and a pH meter</li>
        <li>Drop counter</li>
        <li>Two 50-mL burets</li>
        <li>Buret brush</li>
        <li>BBs container</li>
        <li>Stopwatch</li>
        <li>250-mL beaker</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
      <ul>
        <li>150-mL beakers</li>
        <li>Stir bar</li>
        <li>Ruler</li>
        <li>25-mL graduated cylinder</li>
        <li>Plastic funnel</li>
        <li>Buret clamp</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p><strong><em>Chemicals</em></strong></p>

  <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
      <li>Vegetable oil</li>
      <li>Walnut oil</li>
      <li>Extra virgin olive oil</li>
      <li>Light olive oil</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
      <li>Mobil motor oil</li>
      <li>Quaker State motor oil</li>
      <li>0.025 M sodium hydroxide (NaOH)</li>
      <li>Ethanol</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This gives me some more spacing but I want the "Chemicals" paragraph to be positioned to the left, like the "Materials" paragraph is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping content in a wrapper and then specify property to that wrapper Code:

```html
<div class="labskillsbox"><!--Lab Skills - Janky Code.. -->
  <div style="width:100%; overflow:auto;">
    <p><strong><em>Materials</em></strong></p>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <ul>
        <li>MeasureNet station and a pH meter</li>
        <li>Drop counter</li>
        <li>Two 50-mL burets</li>
        <li>Buret brush</li>
        <li>BBs container</li>
        <li>Stopwatch</li>
        <li>250-mL beaker</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
        <ul>
        <li>150-mL beakers</li>
        <li>Stir bar</li>
        <li>Ruler</li>
        <li>25-mL graduated cylinder</li>
        <li>Plastic funnel</li>
        <li>Buret clamp</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
<div style="width:100%; overflow:auto;">
    <div style="text-align: left;">
    <p><strong>Chemicals</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
    <li>Vegetable oil</li>
    <li>Walnut oil</li>
    <li>Extra virgin olive oil</li>
    <li>Light olive oil</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
    <ul>
    <li>Mobil motor oil</li>
    <li>Quaker State motor oil</li>
    <li>0.025 M sodium hydroxide (NaOH)</li>
    <li>Ethanol</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.